# Paste after last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to paste values from an other tab that is from a IMPORTRANGE, but when I try to paste the value, it is not possible because the value from variable **afterLastRow** transform it in a Boolean and the object **copyValuesToRange** needs a integer.

Tks by help

```
function copiaValoresImportrange() {

  //VARIÁVEL QUE ATRIBUI O SCRIPT PARA A PLANILHA
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //VARIÁVEIS QUE ADQUIREM OS NOMES DAS ABAS DE ORIGEM E DESTINO
  var sheetOrigem  = ss.getSheetByName('ORIGEM');
  var sheetDestino = ss.getSheetByName('DESTINO');
  var afterLastRow = Number(sheetDestino.getLastRow()) + 1;

  //VARIÁVEL QUE VERIFICA AS EXTENSÕES DA PLANILHA DE ORIGEM
  var local = sheetOrigem.getRange(1, 1, afterLastRow, sheetOrigem.getLastColumn());

  //FUNÇÃO QUE COPIA OS DADOS DA PLANILHA DE ORIGEN NA PLANILHA DE DESTINO
  local.copyValuesToRange(sheetDestino, 1, sheetOrigem.getLastColumn(), 1, afterLastRow);

 }
```

Comment: You should be more clear about what is going wrong - the code looks fine to me. Is the problem with copied result, on the spreadsheet? Is the problem occurring when you call the function, with an error being raised at the line `local.copyVa...`? It is unclear from your current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

You don't need `var afterLastRow = Number(sheetDestino.getLastRow()) + 1;`. You can call `sheetDestino.getLastRow() + 1` and get the correct integer.

Second, `copyValuesToRange()` needs the sheet *id*, not the name, [according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangegridid-column-columnend-row-rowend).

Comment: **[Re point 2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))**
 There are two signatures for the `copyValuesToRange()` method.